# neo4j is there a way to allow 'blank' params in a cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a relationship such that `(a)-[:HAS]->(b)`

I want the user to be able to provide `a_id` OR `b_id` and get the data, something along the lines of a cypher query like:

`MATCH (a:A {id: {a_id}})-[:HAS]->(b:B {id: {b_id}}) RETURN *`

But if I don't pass a param `a_id` or `b_id` I Get an error. Is there any way in neo4j of allowing a parameter to not exist and then hence ignoring it?

Maybe something along the lines of:
`CASE {a_id} WHEN NOT NULL THEN ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use named top-level param. For example:

Passed params:

```
:params { "_": { a_id: '123' } }
```

And query:

```
MATCH (a:A {id: {_}.a_id})-[:HAS]->(b:B {id: {_}.b_id}) RETURN *
```

Comment: That may fail since the property will be null if not supplied in the params. I think usage of COALESCE() may fix this: `MATCH (a:A {id: COALESCE({_}.a_id, a.id)})-[:HAS]->(b:B {id: COALESCE({_}.b_id, b.id)}) RETURN *`